# Entity Framework FK from multiple variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

A short description of what i'm trying to achieve:

I have several tables in my DB and i'm creating my DB with code first (with data annotations). I'm trying to mark up several fields to work together as FK for different tables.

The Guid "AccountId" should by it self be a FK to the Account table.

The Guid "AccountId" together with the Guid "CompanyId" together should form the FK to the Company table.

And the "CompanyId" together with the "PersonId" should be the FK for the Person table.

```
[Table("Timestamp")]
public class Timestamp : FullAuditedEntity<Guid>
{
    public const int MaxCardNrLength = 100;

    // The "AccountId" together with "PersonId" should be a FK to the Person table.
    // The "AccountId" together with "CompanyId" should be a FK to the Company table.
    // The "AccountId" standing alone should be a FK to the Account table
    [Required, ForeignKey("Account"), ForeignKey("Company"), ForeignKey("Person")]
    public virtual Guid AccountId { get; set; }

    [Required, ForeignKey("Worksite")]
    public virtual Guid WorksiteId { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(MaxCardNrLength)]
    public virtual string CardNr { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual DateTime StampedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual int StampedType { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Company"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public virtual Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Person"), Column(Order = 2)]
    public virtual Guid PersonId { get; set; }


    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    public virtual Worksite Worksite { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

All these mixes forms unique FK's as a whole, but i cant figure out how to do this with Entity Framework, as it is not valid syntax to write:

```
[Required, ForeignKey("Account"), ForeignKey("Company")]
```

as only one ForeingKey attribute can be set on a single variable.

Is there a way for me to either tag two variables as one collective FK, or any way to do it the way i'm doing now?

Thanks for any help.

**Edit:**
Added a db diagram of what i'm trying to accomplish and updated so that the entire class with all the fields is in here.

[image: What im trying to achieve]

Comment: What do you mean by collective foreign key? Can you please show by example how you want to link these?
And what is this current class where you are having these 6 properties?

Comment: @sachin What i ment by collective foreign key is what i have now added as a comment in the above code, if what i have commented makes sense (i'm not really too experienced with databases). I just need to be able to make the "AccountId" field together with "CompanyId" field to be FK to one table and the same "AccountId" field together with the "PersonId" field to be an FK to a different table. I added a picture displaying how i wanted them to link and i updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reuse a property among many foreign keys you should add `ForeignKey` attribute to the navigation property in the following way:

```
[ForeignKey("AccountId, PersonId")]
public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("AccountId, CompanyId")]
public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fluent configuration for this:[doc](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Timestamp>().HasRequired(t => t.Company ).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t=>new{t.AccountId, t.CompanyId});
```